# group by TABLE_SCHEMA, order by TABLE_NAME

Tags: sql, sql-server

I try to have all the Table_Schema names in order and then order by for each table_schema the table_Name. I try it like this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA , TABLE_NAME, (TABLE_TYPE)  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME DESC
```

Thank you

Comment: The question is unclear, at least to me. Could you please share an example of the output you're trying to get?

Comment: You would have received an error message.  You really should include such messages in your post, as well as what you've tried to do to resolve it, etc.  In this case, reading about GROUP BY (as in relation to your error), in the online help, would have shown it doesn't do what you think it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GROUP BY actually "rolls up" all similar query results into one row. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx

You just want an order by with two columns in it. Try this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA , TABLE_NAME, (TABLE_TYPE)  
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE Table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
ORDER BY TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: I had this first. Maybe I was looking incorrect to the results. But this is correct. So thank you